# CA1811 warning for private imported properties in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, properties, mef

I have a public Controller class inside which I am using following properties

```
[Import]
private TransferRegionViewModel TransferRegionView { get; set; }

[Import]
private Lazy<IVoiceController> VoiceController { get; set; }
```

I am getting following CA warning:

> CA1811 : Microsoft.Performance: 'TransferController.VoiceController.set(Lazy)' appears to have no upstream public or protected callers.

I am using VoicdeController property as :

```
VoiceController.Value.CallTransfer(phoneNumber.PhoneNumber, true);
```

I referred this one - [Properties private set;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366075/c-sharp-properties-private-set) but don't understand if I need to set property internal or private.

Comment: CA1811 means, that `TransferRegionView` and `VoiceController` never called within `Controller` class code. Is this a feature?

Comment: I am using at as edited above. I am not modifying any of that objects properties.

Comment: Your edit also shows that you only access its value but never set it. This could be a logical error. But the CA 1811 warning is simpler in the sense that it warns you that this property is never set. Hence the setter is unused code and wants you to remove it.

Comment: @deathrace.dj: sorry, missed `[Import]` attribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is "normal" warning when using MEF and Code Analysis together.

Your property will be set at run-time by MEF container via reflection, hence, there's no any call of property setter, which could be proven statically by CA. The only way is to suppress this message by [`SuppressMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.suppressmessageattribute.aspx) attribute:

```
[SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Performance", "CA1811:AvoidUncalledPrivateCode")]
[Import]
private Lazy<IVoiceController> VoiceController { get; set; }
```